# need help with choosing a book

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request

Does anyone know a good general measure book that has good examples and theories. I tried reading Royden real analysis but I need more books to help me understand the material. any help is greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: "The Elements of Integration and Lebesgue Measure" by Bartle is really, really great.

Comment: Bruckner's book is quite readable. And Fremlin's measure theory books were written for computers not humans.